# python send data through POST with javascript submit

Tags: javascript, python, authentication, urllib2, form-submit

my  issue with submitting the form from python script .. here is the FORM

```
<form id="userLogin" autocomplete="OFF" action="LoginPage.aspx" method="post" name="userLogin"
<input type="text" class="txt" id="Userid" name="Userid" maxlength="12">
<input type="password" class="txtpwdbox" id="Password" name="Password" readonly="" maxlength="10">
<img style="CURSOR:pointer" onclick="userIdValidation();" src="/ENG/images/but-login-en.gif" id="idSubmit">
```

from the above code , we can noticed that the last line is about submitting but how to do it in python ?

this my python code

```
import urllib,urllib2,cookielib
login_data = urllib.urlencode({'Userid':'test','Password':'123456'})
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
op = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
c = op = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.example.com/Login/LoginPage.aspx', login_data)
print c.read()
```

but it's not submitting .. in case if you wandering what is the `userIdValidation()` function ,, it's basically check if user have filled  the username and password fields then do that command `document.userLogin.submit();`

Comment: the answer is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703772/sending-form-data-to-aspx-page

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) ([PyPI page](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/)). Not sure whether it handles Javascript, but it helped me a lot at navigating between pages and submitting forms. Furthermore, you would get rid of the cookie management.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are fetch that page from an .net framework implementation site.("LoginPage.aspx" here)

there is many sites of .net framework are enable the PageView property,it's one of the maintain page's state method, but it will attach some of the data request is initiated

So, if you want to post a request, don't forget the PageView or other .net framework data.

Comment: i don't get it , can you explain more please ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try above 
but when you build a opener "op" by

> op = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))

why you use

> urllib2.urlopen('https://www.example.com/Login/LoginPage.aspx', login_data)

this cannot pass the cookie