# Sending form data to aspx page

Tags: python, screen-scraping, urllib2

There is a need to do a search on the website

```
    url = r'http://www.cpso.on.ca/docsearch/'
```

this is an aspx page (I'm beginning this trek as of yesterday, sorry for noob questions)

using BeautifulSoup, I can get the __VIEWSTATE and __EVENTVALIDATION like this:

```
    viewstate = soup.find('input', {'id' : '__VIEWSTATE'})['value']
    eventval = soup.find('input', {'id' : '__EVENTVALIDATION'})['value']
```

and the header can be set like this:

```
    headers = {'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.13) Gecko/2009073022 Firefox/3.0.13',
'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml; q=0.9,*/*; q=0.8',
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
```

if you go to the webpage, the only values I really want to pass are the first name and last name...

```
    LN = "smith"
    FN = "a"
    data = {"__VIEWSTATE":viewstate,"__EVENTVALIDATION":ev,
    "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$MainContentControl1$ctl00$txtLastName":LN, 
    "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$MainContentControl1$ctl00$txtFirstName":FN}
```

so putting it all together its like this:

```
    import urllib
    import urllib2
    import urlparse
    import BeautifulSoup

    url = r'http://www.cpso.on.ca/docsearch/'
    html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(html)

    viewstate = soup.find('input', {'id' : '__VIEWSTATE'})['value']
    ev = soup.find('input', {'id' : '__EVENTVALIDATION'})['value']
    headers = {'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.13) Gecko/2009073022 Firefox/3.0.13',
        'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml; q=0.9,*/*; q=0.8',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

    LN = "smith"
    FN = "a"
    data = {"__VIEWSTATE":viewstate,"__EVENTVALIDATION":ev,
            "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$MainContentControl1$ctl00$txtLastName":LN, 
            "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$MainContentControl1$ctl00$txtFirstName":FN}

    data = urllib.urlencode(data)
    request = urllib2.Request(url,data,headers)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    newsoup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(response)
    for i in newsoup:
        print i
```

The problem is that it doesnt really seem to give me the results... don't know if I need to supply every value for every textbox in the form or what... maybe I'm just not doing it properly.  anyways, just hoping someone could set me straight.  I thought I had it but i would expect to see a list of doctors and contact info.

any insight is much appreciated, I have used beautifulsoup before, but I think my problem is just sending Request and having the right amount of info in the data part.

Thanks!

Comment: hi @nasir, the output is just the beautifulsoup parsing the initial URL variable as before... so its not really giving me anything helpful other than not erroring out when doing the urllib2.request(url,data,headers) piece...  Thanks,

Comment: I made some ties with no success. Strange to me. I tried simulating the whole request by adding all request headers and form inputs. still no lock and the response has `Connection: close` but it should have a 302 code. I will try to see if I can resolve it.

Comment: You might have better luck using mechanize.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it @Nasir

Comment: @That1Guy no I am not receiving errors, I'm just not getting the expected results I would expect by putting in the values and clicking the search button.

Comment: @pguardiario, thanks, I had seen others using mechanize, but have not dabbled with it yet.  will try that next... Thanks all!

Comment: @pguardiario Thanks for that tip...  actually works great now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

took advice from @pguardiario and went the mechanize route... much simpler

```
import mechanize
      
url = r'http://www.cpso.on.ca/docsearch/'
request = mechanize.Request(url)
response = mechanize.urlopen(request)
forms = mechanize.ParseResponse(response, backwards_compat=False)
response.close()

form = forms[0]

form['ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$MainContentControl1$ctl00$txtLastName']='Smith'
form['ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$MainContentControl1$ctl00$txtPostalCode']='K1H'

print mechanize.urlopen(form.click()).read()
```

I am a long way from finishing, but this is getting me a lot further.

Comment: Thanks Randall. I copied your code, changed the url and form vars added a "print form" and I was up and running on an ASPX scraping project in less than 2 mins. Saved me hours of mucking around.